# Component get Re-render in case no change in Input Properties and strategy is OnPush

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am facing a weird issue that DOM gets re-render in case of any input key pressed in input field. I am using FormControl. sibling component to the input field on DOM has **OnPush**
strategy.

when i enter anything or click in the input field my DOM get re-render, input field value has no effect on the sibling component so its **@Input** properties remain same( Strategy of this component is onPush) but it re-render causing no call of lifecycle method like **ngOnInit** , **ngOnChanges**.

because of this unpredicted component re-rendering causing distorting of component UI because no lifecycle get call like **ngOnInit** **ngOnChanges** so no initialisation function call of that component.

so component get render with previous values can anyone tell me why this is happen.

is this because of FormControl i am using or something else.

Comment: if you have a function call in your template that is getting a value from the component, then it will cause the template to rerender in a loop.

Comment: @behruz as i mention above both are independent component on the page.